# Switching language in polylang

Tags: wordpress, lang, switching, polylang

I have a problem with `polylang`.

For example, the default language is `PL` and additional `EN` and `DE`. Everything is good, but when you switch to `EN` and close the browser, after entering the main domain again, `EN` is active. Clicking on `PL` it does not want to switch anything and in the address bar is always `www.mypage.pl/en/`. Even if I remove it from the address en it goes back to it.

Cleaning cookies in the browser does not give anything.

What may be the problem? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I solved the problem by removing the following code from the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```